# Using jquery to remember which tab was open when form saved?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tabs

I followed [this tutorial](http://fearlessflyer.com/2012/01/how-to-create-super-easy-jquery-tabbed-containers/) to make a tabbed menu for a WordPress plugin I've created. I would like the tab that was open when the form was last saved to be the tab that is open when the page reloads.

I have 6 tabs, Settings, and Group 1 through Group 5. If they are on Group 3 and click to save the form, right now it reloads on the Settings tab. I would like it to open on Group 3. I was thinking of dropping a cookie every time they clicked on a new tab, but that doesn't seem like the cleanest way to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: With the default implementation of the jQuery UI tabs http://jqueryui.com/tabs/ you are able to link directly to a particular tab via url address.  Hence you could redirect to a particular location based on a hidden value you send to PHP in your form.  Or you could go the cookie route as outlined here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18687252/show-form-after-click-back-button/18687625#18687625

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` depending on your usage. They can be used to store temporary / persistent data at the client browser:

```
// set data
sessionStorage.setItem("currentTab", tabid);

// get data
var tabid = sessionStorage.getItem("currentTab");
```

Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage?redirect=no) out for more information.

Comment: This works great on Chrome. I'll have to see how far back this goes as far as compatibility on all browsers, but thanks!